# Bring an image from my twitter account to Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I want to insert *my twitter account profile photo* in the RMarkdown document I am writing, nevertheless it is not showing any output at all.

Below is the code I am using:

```
![](https://twitter.com/BIRASAFABRICE/photo)
```

I tried to search through internet but the solutions being are not helping me. where am I going wrong with this code? or how do I need to do it? thank you for your usual help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mhovd suggested, I inspected the picture I wanted to include in the `RMarkdown` document and used the below code to read it in jpg:

`knitr::include_graphics("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1051755261583601666/roHaL2s1_400x400.jpg")`

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the link to the actual image resource, not a page where your photo is in focus.

Right click photo, inspect element, and then you will find the correct link
https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1051755261583601666/roHaL2s1_400x400.jpg

You can then use this in your RMarkdown document.